# Cannot connect to localhost

Tags: sql-server

I receive the following error randomly when I connect to SQL via `SSMSE 2005`.

> Additional Information: A connection was successfully established with
>   the server, but then an error occurred during the login
>   process.(provider: Shared Memory Provider,error:0 no process is on the
>   other end of the pipe.) (Microsoft SQL Server Error, error: 233).

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: not a programming question. Make sure your SQL server is listening the port.

Comment: No, my web config is already using SQL authentication.

Comment: It is indeed listening to port. WHen I close SSMSE  and again try to connect, everything goes fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try first checking if the following protocols are enabled from the SQL Server Configuration Manager:

1. Named Pipes
2. TCP/IP

Also, check from the Surface Area Configuration Manager to find out if your SQL Express Instance is configured to accept remote connections.

Please refer the following link for more help:

http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326280.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the web.config connectionString cause the result. Replace the default authentication details of Integrated Security=True:

```
connectionString

="Data Source=STL-COPELAND\SQLSERVER2005;Initial Catalog=IC;Integrated Security=True"
```

to use "User ID=sa Password=pwd"  for example in the connection string:

```
connectionString

="Data Source=STL-COPELAND\SQLSERVER2005;Initial Catalog=IC;User ID=sa Password=pwd"
```